# Is there a way to unset every session variables excluding desired variable(s)?

Tags: php, session

I have a pretty basic cart set up, my "clear cart" function runs the following PHP, the intention is to clear the cart without losing session data that needs to be kept (log-in username/email/etc).

The code I have works for what I want (just toying with PHP) but it doesn't seem very efficient and I  am wondering if there's an easier way of unsetting everything excluding specific session variables. It seems like there has to be an alternative to listing everything you want to get rid of if you only want to keep 2 variables and want to get rid of 9.

A way to unset everything excluding user data that is kept/persistent regardless of whether something is being ordered or not.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 unset
(
    $_SESSION['pcode1'],  
    $_SESSION['uprice1'],  
    $_SESSION['quantity1'],
    $_SESSION['pcode2'],  
    $_SESSION['uprice2'], 
    $_SESSION['quantity2'],
    $_SESSION['pcode3'], 
    $_SESSION['uprice3'],  
    $_SESSION['quantity3'] 
); 
header('Location: cart.php'); 
exit; 

?>
```

Tl;dr
Is there a way to unset all session data excluding specific variables.

Comment: Use a loop and and if statement. That's it.

Comment: ? I don't understand the response, I don't want to unset the entire session I want to keep specific variables an unset everything else.

Comment: Unset the `$_SESSION` values that you don't need then?

Comment: @BrandonWhite 
That totally works and if you look at my code is what i've done, what I want to know is can it be inverted ? Instead of unsetting each individual variable you don't want could you just select variables to not be unset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($_SESSION as $kill=>$v){
    if (!in_array($kill,ARRAY OF WANTED KEYS))
      {unset ($_SESSION[$kill]);}
    }
```

Demo:http://codepad.viper-7.com/t8HU4L

Comment: basically what I told the OP earlier and in a nutshell, but decided to delete that comment (must've been over their head). Now the proof is no longer in the pudding.

Comment: if I do recall, it went something like: *"assign session arrays to variables and use in_array() with the `!` operator"*.

Comment: That's not a bad way to go about it thanks !

Also @Fred-ii- never saw your comment sorry, not really sure what the point of telling me about a comment you deleted is though ?

Comment: @Spooler that comment stuck around for quite a bit. When I don't see upvotes or feedback about it, I simply delete it. Many times it's probably because it's not what they're looking for and I make way for other comments in order not to tie up the comments area.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you can have half my points, or a cookie, your call

Comment: @Dagon I'll take the cookie ;-) I just happen to have the munchies.

Comment: @Spooler No worries. Dagon gave you a good solution and that's all good with me ;-)

Comment: @Spooler Plus, using the in_array() method,  gives you a lot more control and much cleaner. You just need to add (or delete) to the array as needed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- agree'd it's a very flexible (and cool) way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks, the only way to unset a specific set of `$_SESSION` variables is to manually unset each of those.

Another alternative would be to store the two variables you would like, then run `unset($_SESSION)`, following that just re-set the new variables with the old data. Eg:

```
session_start();

$tmp1 = $_SESSION['variable1'];
$tmp2 = $_SESSION['variable2']

unset($_SESSION); 

$_SESSION['variable1'] = $tmp1;
$_SESSION['variable2'] = $tmp2;
```

Comment: Would totally work, not something I had thought of. I do prefer Dagon's response, thanks though !